# Python – ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm really new to programming, and I can't figure out how to use a Numpy array to be manipulated in a function such as `P**2`.

```
import math
import numpy
span_x = numpy.array([0,250,500,750,1000])
P = span_x
example = P**2
span_y = [example for i in P]
y = float(input("Enter y: "))
bracket1 = min(span_y, lambda span_y: abs(span_y-y))
if bracket1 < y:
    for i in span_y:
        bracket2 = span_y[span_y.index(bracket1) + 1]
else:
    for i in span_y:
        bracket2 = span_y[span_y.index(bracket1) - 1]
print "Brackets: ", bracket1, bracket2
```

I've tried not using a Numpy array, but received a TypeError.

My main issue is that I have this array of x-values (`span_x`) that I want to put into a function like `P**2` and get y-values (`span_y`) in an array. Then, the user inputs a y-value and I want to check which y-value in `span_y` is closest to this input, and that is `bracket1`. `bracket2` is the second closest y-value. I would love some help!

Comment: Please, always post full tracebacks.

Comment: Please, do a search on the error - see the 'Related' column to see how many other SO questions have the same subject line.

Comment: Does the `ValueError` occur on line: `if bracket1 < y:`?

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. The error occurs at: `bracket2 = span_y[span_y.index(bracket1) - 1]`

Comment: As `Alik` noted `bracket1` is not an array like one those in `span_y`.  You need to test how you generate it.

Comment: In your example all the elements of span_y are the same array.  Is that intentional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`span_y` is a list of 1D-arrays so `min` doesn't work as you expect and returns a function. After that `span_y.index(bracket1)` raises an exception. `span_y` should be initialized like this

```
span_y = list(example)
```

Pass your key function (lambda) in `min` as a named parameter as said [in documention](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#min).

```
bracket1 = min(span_y, key = lambda span_y: abs(span_y-y))
```

Answer (score 1):

In NumPy you can and should vectorize the operations like:

```
span_y = span_x**2
y = float(input("Enter y: "))
bracket1 = np.array((span_y, np.abs(span_y - y))).min(axis=0)
bracket2 = np.zeros_like(bracket1)
bracket2[ bracket1 < y ] = np.roll(span_y, 1)
bracket2[ bracket1 >= y] = np.roll(span_y, -1)
```

Comment: I tried this, and it got rid of my Error Message, but when I `print bracket1, bracket2` both outputs display long arrays when the answers should really just each be one value. Why is that please?

Comment: @theo1010 it was a bit unclear from your question to understand what you really wanted, so I built this example using vectors... I hope this example clarifies your doubts